# android- edit text - get phone number in international format like +xxxxxxxxx

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have edit text element that will get the phone number, I need the phone number to be include country code in +xxx format. I am using `android:inputType="phone"`

how I can force the input to have that +Countrycode in the number?

I want something like  Google contacts if possible or similar. If instead of flag just the country code is possible , that is also OK.

[image]

Comment: I just answered a similar question, hope that it helps you too. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19789317/983741

Comment: well i need this to be changeable .you can check how it works in gmail contacts , Add new contact or edit a contact

Comment: Here you will click on the flag and u can select from a list

Comment: if this isnt possible I will need to have some method to just force the user to input the number in + (country code) (phone number) format

Comment: You can use spinner besides the edittext in that case.

Comment: @dmSherazi Are you get the answer ??

Comment: @sushildlh please check the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I used [IntlPhoneInput](https://github.com/rimoto/IntlPhoneInput). Although I had to tweak it for my usage but this is a nice library.

Its available on gradle.

```
compile 'net.rimoto:intlphoneinput:0.9.3'
```