# How to set some portion of EditText non-erasable

Tags: java, android, onclick, android-edittext

I am trying to add a hard coded text in an EditText onClick. Which is OK so far. But the pre-added text is removable. Is there any way to make it Hard coded, so that the user cannot remove it but type in front of it in the same EditText field.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788386/set-unchangeable-some-part-of-edittext-android/19789317#19789317

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `EditText.addTextChangedListener` ,by using this you can do the same.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the `TextView` and `EditText` inside the Layout and set the `EditText` and `TextView` background transparent  and set the layout background as `EditText` bacground

```
<RelativeLayout
 android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
 android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" >

<TextView 
  android:id="@+id/constant_text"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_centerVertical="true"
  android:text="HardCodedText"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
  android:background="@android:color/transparent" />


<EditText 
  android:id="@+id/et_cc"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/constant_text"
  android:textColor="#000000"  
  android:background="@android:color/transparent"
  android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```