# How to set an non editable text on left side of edit text in android?

Tags: android, text

As we all know that we can set a `drawable_left` on the `EditText` using

```
edittext.setcCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon,0,0,0);
```

Is it possible to set a non editable text say "A" on the left side of the edit text?

Comment: use `RelativeLayout`

Comment: did you saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195207/put-constant-text-inside-edittext-which-should-be-non-editable-android  and  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19789317/1564821

Comment: @SpringBreaker..yes i saw,but the user can enter before the settext..but i don't want to do any action before text.

Comment: are you willing to implement `android:hint`? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:hint

Answer (score 2):

You can do this like this (The values are for example):

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="A"
              android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
    <EditText android:layout_width="100dp"
              android:layout_height="25dp"
              android:id="@+id/editTextView"
              android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Then try with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788386/set-unchangeable-some-part-of-edittext-android/19789317#19789317 - Convert the text to a drawable and paste it into the editText