# How to make part of text in EditText non-removable when using RedMadRobot's input-mask-android?

Tags: android, input-mask

I am using RedMadRobot's input-mask-android library to set input mask to EditText for entering phone numbers.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static String INPUT_MASK_PHONE = "{998} [00] [000]-[00]-[00]";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login);

        MaskedTextChangedListener maskedTextChangedListener = new MaskedTextChangedListener(
                INPUT_MASK_PHONE,
                true,
                login,
                null,
                new MaskedTextChangedListener.ValueListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(boolean b, @NotNull String s) {

                    }
                }
        );

        login.addTextChangedListener(maskedTextChangedListener);
        login.setSelection(login.length());

    }

}
```

I am setting '998', which should not be removed when user tries remove. Now '998' can be removed.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:text="998"/>
```

How to make '998' not removable?

Comment: Whether its always 998? or the number can be changed? Just a suggestion: why don't u put **998** in a **TextView** and accept remaining from edittext?

Comment: @Raghavendra, good idea. But I am trying to put whole value (998 XX YYY- YY-YY) into EditText

Comment: @Raghavendra, it is always 998

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788386/set-unchangeable-some-part-of-edittext-android and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195207/put-constant-text-inside-edittext-which-should-be-non-editable-android

Comment: @Raghavendra, thank you for link

Answer (score 0):

Try out this sample

```
private final String mMobileInitial ="+974 ";
EditText login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login);
login.setText(mMobileInitial);
Selection.setSelection(login.getText(), login.getText().length());
        login.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(!s.toString().startsWith(mMobileInitial)){
                    login.setText(mMobileInitial);
                    Selection.setSelection(login.getText(), login.getText().length());
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But I tried this solution and it is conflicting with input-mask-android. It is behaving very strange.