# multiline edittext where parts are not editable, like fill in the blanks

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, android-custom-view

I need to have a view which contains textview and edittext.

Example:

```
Yay! you made it to ______ We should hang out! feel ____ to follow me.
```

Above "_____" could be of any length and it should feel like a paragraph in the end. Rest of the text given above is not changeable. Just like fill in the blanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I'd suggest to use https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout with mix of textviews and edittext.

Comment: Is it dynamic textview and edittext or will it be fixed number of textviews and edittext.. If it is fixed, please provide what you want to display in textview.. Thanks..

Comment: @UmangBurman - dynamic. It can contain any number or textview or editTexts. Better call them label and placeholders as the whole solution could be a single EditText just handling the requirement.

Comment: @DipenShah - I used a single EditText text and then converted spans into Drawable spans inside for labels so that they can look as unchangeable, however after pressing back button they are getting deleted.

Comment: @HishamMuneer If it is dynamic, How the data will be added to the TextView, is it from the server? As I understand, the data in the EditText can be added dynamically at runtime. So how will you add data in TextView is my question.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my perspective, a fill-in-the-blank widget should do the following:

1. Allow only certain identified portions of the text to be changed. The rest of the text is locked.
2. Not allow cursor movement into the locked text.
3. Flow from line to line like `EditText`.
4. Be generalized with variable placement of blanks.

Here is an implementation of such a widget based upon `EditText`. Editable spans are set up using a span (`BlanksSpan`) extended from `StyleSpan`. A blank span is identified by five underscores ("_____") in the text. Cursor movement is controlled in `OnSelectionChanged()` and various `EditText` callbacks. Changes to the text is monitor by a `TextWatcher` and adjustments to the displayed text are made there.

Here is the video of the widget in use:

[image]

**FillInBlanksEditText.java**

```
public class FillInBlanksEditText extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText  
    implements View.OnFocusChangeListener, TextWatcher {  
    private int mLastSelStart;  
    private int mLastSelEnd;  
    private BlanksSpan mSpans[];  
    private Editable mUndoChange;  
    private BlanksSpan mWatcherSpan;  

    public FillInBlanksEditText(Context context) {  
        super(context);  
        init();  
    }  

    public FillInBlanksEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {  
        super(context, attrs);  
        init();  
    }  

    public FillInBlanksEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {  
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);  
        init();  
    }  

    private void init() {  
        mSpans = setSpans();  
        setOnFocusChangeListener(this);  
    }  

    @Override  
  public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {  
        mSpans = null;  
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);  
        Editable e = getEditableText();  
        mSpans = e.getSpans(0, e.length(), BlanksSpan.class);  
    }  

    @Override  
  public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {  
        if (hasFocus) {  
            addTextChangedListener(this);  
            if (findInSpan(getSelectionStart(), getSelectionEnd()) != null) {  
                mLastSelStart = getSelectionStart();  
                mLastSelEnd = getSelectionEnd();  
            } else if (findInSpan(mLastSelStart, mLastSelEnd) == null) {  
                setSelection(getEditableText().getSpanStart(mSpans[0]));  
            }  
        } else {  
            removeTextChangedListener(this);  
        }  
    }  

    @Override  
  protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {  
        if (!isFocused() || mSpans == null ||  
            (getSelectionStart() == mLastSelStart && getSelectionEnd() == mLastSelEnd)) {  
            return;  
        }  

        // The selection must be completely within a Blankspan.  
  final BlanksSpan span = findInSpan(selStart, selEnd);  
        if (span == null) {  
            // Current selection is not within a Blankspan. Restore selection to prior location.  
  moveCursor(mLastSelStart);  
        } else if (selStart > getEditableText().getSpanStart(span) + span.getDataLength()) {  
            // Acceptable location for selection (within a Blankspan).  
 // Make sure that the cursor is at the end of the entered data.  mLastSelStart = getEditableText().getSpanStart(span) + span.getDataLength();  
            mLastSelEnd = mLastSelStart;  
            moveCursor(mLastSelStart);  

        } else {  
            // Just capture the placement.  
  mLastSelStart = selStart;  
            mLastSelEnd = selEnd;  
        }  
        super.onSelectionChanged(mLastSelStart, mLastSelEnd);  
    }  

    // Safely move the cursor without directly invoking setSelection from onSelectionChange.  
  private void moveCursor(final int selStart) {  
        post(new Runnable() {  
            @Override  
  public void run() {  
                setSelection(selStart);  
            }  
        });  
        // Stop cursor form jumping on move.  
  getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {  
            @Override  
  public boolean onPreDraw() {  
                getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);  
                return false;  
            }  
        });  
    }  

    @Nullable  
  private BlanksSpan findInSpan(int selStart, int selEnd) {  
        for (BlanksSpan span : mSpans) {  
            if (selStart >= getEditableText().getSpanStart(span) &&  
                selEnd <= getEditableText().getSpanEnd(span)) {  
                return span;  
            }  
        }  
        return null;  
    }  

    // Set up a Blankspan to cover each occurrence of BLANKS_TOKEN.  
  private BlanksSpan[] setSpans() {  
        Editable e = getEditableText();  
        String s = e.toString();  
        int offset = 0;  
        int blanksOffset;  

        while ((blanksOffset = s.substring(offset).indexOf(BLANKS_TOKEN)) != -1) {  
            offset += blanksOffset;  
            e.setSpan(new BlanksSpan(Typeface.BOLD), offset, offset + BLANKS_TOKEN.length(),  
                      Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);  
            offset += BLANKS_TOKEN.length();  
        }  
        return e.getSpans(0, e.length(), BlanksSpan.class);  
    }  

    // Check change to make sure that it is acceptable to us.  
  @Override  
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {  
        mWatcherSpan = findInSpan(start, start + count);  
        if (mWatcherSpan == null) {  
            // Change outside of a Blankspan. Just put things back the way they were.  
 // Do this in afterTextChaanged.  mUndoChange = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(s);  
        } else {  
            // Change is OK. Track data length.  
  mWatcherSpan.adjustDataLength(count, after);  
        }  
    }  

    @Override  
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {  
        // Do nothing...  
  }  

    @Override  
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {  
        if (mUndoChange == null) {  
            // The change is legal. Modify the contents of the span to the format we want.  
  CharSequence newContents = mWatcherSpan.getFormattedContent(s);  
            if (newContents != null) {  
                removeTextChangedListener(this);  
                int selection = getSelectionStart();  
                s.replace(s.getSpanStart(mWatcherSpan), s.getSpanEnd(mWatcherSpan), newContents);  
                setSelection(selection);  
                addTextChangedListener(this);  
            }  
        } else {  
            // Illegal change - put things back the way they were.  
  removeTextChangedListener(this);  
            setText(mUndoChange);  
            mUndoChange = null;  
            addTextChangedListener(this);  
        }  
    }  

    @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")  
    public static class BlanksSpan extends StyleSpan {  
        private int mDataLength;  

        public BlanksSpan(int style) {  
            super(style);  
        }  

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")  
        public BlanksSpan(@NonNull Parcel src) {  
            super(src);  
        }  

        public void adjustDataLength(int count, int after) {  
            mDataLength += after - count;  
        }  

        @Nullable  
  public CharSequence getFormattedContent(Editable e) {  
            if (mDataLength == 0) {  
                return BLANKS_TOKEN;  
            }  
            int spanStart = e.getSpanStart(this);  
            return (e.getSpanEnd(this) - spanStart > mDataLength)  
                ? e.subSequence(spanStart, spanStart + mDataLength)  
                : null;  
        }  

        public int getDataLength() {  
            return mDataLength;  
        }  

    }  

    @SuppressWarnings({"FieldCanBeLocal", "unused"})  
    private static final String TAG = "FillInBlanksEditText";  
    private static final String BLANKS_TOKEN = "_____";  

}
```

**activity_main.java**
A sample layout.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.example.fillintheblanks.FillInBlanksEditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Yay! You made it to _____. We should hang out! Feel _____ to follow me."
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.example.fillintheblanks.FillInBlanksEditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="_____ says that it is time to _____. Are you _____?"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/editText" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

A few things to note:

1. In extracted mode, cursor placement jumps around if a touch is made outside of a `BlanksSpan`. Things still work but misbehave a little.
2. The length of the blanks fields is fixed, but it can be made variable in length with some additional work.
3. The action mode in the control needs some work based upon requirements.

Comment: **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
        at FillInBlanksEditText.onFocusChange(FillInBlanksEditText.java:66)**

Comment: @Cheticamp, any update on the above code, i am also facing  too..

Answer (score 2):

> multiline edittext where parts are not editable, like fill in the blanks

You can  use a **`TextWatcher()`** for this requirement

Try this  he is the little work around for this

> MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    EditText myEditText;
    String startText = "I'm The First Part";
    String lastText = "I'm The Last Part";

    SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final SpannableStringBuilder firstStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(startText);
        final SpannableStringBuilder lastStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(lastText);

        StyleSpan firstStyleSpan = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);

        firstStringBuilder.setSpan(firstStyleSpan, 0, firstStringBuilder.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); // make first 4 characters Bold
        lastStringBuilder.setSpan(firstStyleSpan, 0, lastStringBuilder.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE); // make first 4 characters Bold

        myEditText = findViewById(R.id.myEditText);


        spannableStringBuilder.append(firstStringBuilder);
        spannableStringBuilder.append("   ");
        spannableStringBuilder.append(lastStringBuilder);

        myEditText.setText(spannableStringBuilder);
        Selection.setSelection(myEditText.getText(), startText.length() + 1);

        myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                if (!s.toString().startsWith(firstStringBuilder.toString())
                        || !s.toString().contains(lastText)) {
                    Log.e("StringBuilder_TAG", spannableStringBuilder.toString());

                    myEditText.setText(spannableStringBuilder);
                    Selection.setSelection(myEditText.getText(), myEditText.getText().length() - lastStringBuilder.length() - 1);
                } else {

                    spannableStringBuilder.clear();
                    spannableStringBuilder.append(s.toString());
                    Log.e("My_TAG", spannableStringBuilder.toString());

                }

            }
        });

    }


}
```

> layout.activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/myEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="5dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

> Here is the output video of above code https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pfhUzLiFD6U

using above code you able to make not editble first and last parts of `editext`

**Note**

You can also use a **`TextDrawable`**
 here are some links for that

- [How to put text in a drawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972445/how-to-put-text-in-a-drawable)
- https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable
- [Set unchangeable some part of editText android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788386/set-unchangeable-some-part-of-edittext-android)

You can also create a custom `EditText` for this

- [Adding a prefix to an EditText](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/adding-a-prefix-to-an-edittext-2a17a62c77e1)

You can also use [**`InputFilter`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36389032/7666442)

Comment: I think you need to insert exit texts wherever you want user input.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution one**

Try using flexbox-layout - https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout.

**Solution Two**

Use textWatcher

**Solution Three**

- Use html, css and javascript to design a simple webpage.
- Use webview to load the html file.

Answer (score 0):

Follow @Cheticamp 's answer, it works when you set a SpannableString in a setText() method.

Also you should override setText() method and set Spans to mSpans:

```
@Override
public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
    mSpans = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(text).getSpans(0, text.length(), BlanksSpan.class);
    Log.d(TAG, "setText: " + mSpans.length);
    super.setText(text, type);
}
```

if you don't set a SpannableString, Editable interface will get a simple String without Spans.
So if you call methods like:

1. Editable.getSpanStart(tag) returns -1;
2. Editable.getSpanEnd(tag) returns -1;
3. Editable.getSpans(start, end, Class) returns empty array