# How to put Textview and multiline edittext in same line like cmd

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I want to create view like cmd.The view start with textview after that edittext starts. And Edittext will be multi link .[image]

Comment: [multiline edittext where parts are not editable, like fill in the blanks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52791180/7666442)

Comment: try creating dynamic editText then you will be able to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't create a non-rectangle view, so, it's impossible to archive your idea. emmmm... maybe you can try that just use only one EditText.

let user input something, and you output something, just append them into EditText.

just listen the keyboard event, check if allow user to delete content from your EditText.