# Create multiline edittext where parts are not editable, like fill in the blanks quiz in SoloLearn

Tags: java, android

I need to have a edittext which contains words and blanks.

```
Create multiline edittext where parts are not _______, like fill in the blanks quiz in __________
```

Above "_____" could be of any length and it should feel like a paragraph in the end. Rest of the text given above is not changeable. Just like fill in the blanks.

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53047969/3760297) but this answer is very basic and not like SoloLearn

> I mean something like this:

[image]

Comment: What is the answer you linked missing exactly?

Comment: @Nicolas I  add a gif for you

Comment: I don't have experience with spans unfortunately. Do you think you could use a subclass of underline span instead of `BlankSpan`, fill it with spaces initially, and as user edits, you add or remove spaces as needed? This way it would break correctly at the end of the line.

Comment: @Nicolas Thank you, in fact the user cannot reduce or decrease empty spaces, in other words the number of empty spaces is fixed and the user cannot type more than that.